# Caluclated Field/Formula: Automated Month Counter

Tags: excel, calculated-column-formula

I have a "Start Date" field and a "Months in Process" field. Upon changing the start date, I need the "Months in Process" field to start ticking from 0 and increase in increments of 1 month. Everytime I change the date, I want it to return to 0 and start ticking up again.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible with a calculated column as the data for the column is only calculated when the item is updated.  You might can achieve this with the Client Side Render of a custom column in SharePoint 2013.